# Calling derived class static method from base class static method

Tags: visual-c++, inheritance, gcc, static

I have read the following SO questions:

- [Calling derived class function from base class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4869216/501663)
- [Call derived class method from base class reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4209000/501663)
- [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/501663)

however I have a slightly different issue regarding static methods and the difference between Visual-c++ and gcc.

I have a class which bundles a few static methods related to a given task. I want to implement a simple version of each method, and allow a more efficient implementation in the future. I do this by implementing all the methods in a base class, and calling the methods from the derived class. This way methods which have 'newer' implementation will hide the 'old' implementation. My problem is that when one method `g()` calls another method `f()`, I want to verify that the implementation in the derived class is called (if it exists). I cannot use virtual methods, since my methods are all static. In visual-c++ the following code is doing what I have just described, but gcc won't compile - actually I am surprised that visual-c++ compiles OK. (I need my code to compile on both)

```
struct Base {
    static void f () {}
    static void g () { Derived::f(); } //--- visual-c++ compiles ok; gcc: "'Derived' was not declared in this scope"
};
struct Derived : public Base {
    static void f () {}
};

Derived::g ();
```

My question is, how come visual-c++ is not complaining, and how can I solve it in gcc without a radical change to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok an answer that was given (and deleted before I got the chance to comment/accept) made me understand how simple the solution is (or in other words, how stupid my question was :) )

All I have to do is separate the declaration from the implementation (it was all in a single h file - bad coding, I know, it was a permanent 'temporary' solution)

```
struct Base {
    static void f ();
    static void g ();
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    static void f();
};

int main() {
        Derived::g ();
        return 0;
}

void Base::f () {}

void Base::g () { Derived::f(); } 

void Derived::f() {}
```

Comment: I deleted the answer because I am pretty much sure the code in Q won't compile without any compiler extensions.I don't know why it would compile in MSVC, perhaps a compiler extension.

Comment: I think generally MSVC is less strict than GCC (it's not the first time I encounter a code which compile in MSCV but not in GCC). Anyway thanks, your answer made me think a little bit and find the trivial solution...